# Extract p value from multiple linear regression f-test

Tags: r

I am doing a hypothesis test to test to see if my model is significant and I want to extract the p-value.

So I know that you do `summary(mymodel)$fstatistic[1])` to find the test statistic.

and you can do `summary(mymodel)$coeff[2,4]` to find the p-value, but this only works for simple linear regression since the p values are the same for t and f test.

I want to get the p-value by itself without any libraries. Can it be done? I can't seem to find an answer for this..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: its not actaullt returned, but printed using the `stats:::print.summary.lm` method. So calculate manually (as in the print method) ie `fs = s$fstatistic ;
pf(fs["value"], fs["numdf"], fs["dendf"], lower=FALSE)`

Comment: I'm still not sure what line of code I need to type to output the p-value that is not like a function? if that makes sense

Comment: nvm I figured it out, thanks.

Comment: yes, it makes sense. You can't just grab a number fro the results of the `summary` object, as it is only generated in the `print`ing of the summary (ie see `stats:::print.summary.lm` ). So you need to calculate it using the f-statistic, and degrees of freedom (all of which are retuned by `summary`)

Comment: f = summary(mymodel)$fstatistic,
p = pf(f[1], f[2], f[3], lower.tail = FALSE),
p